# Unable to configure AWX with Okta

Tags: authentication

I have been trying to configure SAML (okta) on AWX without success for some time now.
The user is getting a `400: Bad Request Error Code: GENERAL_NONSUCCESS` error.

The current SAML configuration:

```
SAML_AUTO_CREATE_OBJECTS: false
SOCIAL_AUTH_SAML_SP_ENTITY_ID: 'AWXURL'
SOCIAL_AUTH_SAML_SP_PUBLIC_CERT: "{{ lookup('ansible.builtin.file', './cert.pem') }}"
SOCIAL_AUTH_SAML_SP_PRIVATE_KEY: "{{ lookup('ansible.builtin.file', './key.pem') }}"
SOCIAL_AUTH_SAML_ORG_INFO: {
  "en-US": {
    "name": "OKTA",
    "url": "AWXURL",
    "displayname": "OKTA"
  }
}
SOCIAL_AUTH_SAML_TECHNICAL_CONTACT: {
  "emailAddress": "foo@bar.com",
  "givenName": "FOO"
}
SOCIAL_AUTH_SAML_SUPPORT_CONTACT: {
  "emailAddress": "foo@bar.com",
  "givenName": "FOO"
}
SOCIAL_AUTH_SAML_ENABLED_IDPS: {
  "okta": {
    "attr_email": "Email",
    "attr_first_name": "FirstName",
    "attr_last_name": "LastName",
    "attr_user_permanent_id": "name_id",
    "attr_username": "UserName",
    "entity_id": "http://www.okta.com/ID",
    "url": "https://ORG.oktapreview.com/app/APP/ID/sso/saml",
    "x509cert": "MIIIIIIIIIIIIII"
  }
}
SOCIAL_AUTH_SAML_SECURITY_CONFIG:
  requestedAuthnContext: false
SOCIAL_AUTH_SAML_SP_EXTRA:
SOCIAL_AUTH_SAML_EXTRA_DATA:
SOCIAL_AUTH_SAML_ORGANIZATION_MAP: {
  "FOO": {
    "admins": true,
    "users": true
  }
}
SOCIAL_AUTH_SAML_TEAM_MAP:
SOCIAL_AUTH_SAML_ORGANIZATION_ATTR: {}
SOCIAL_AUTH_SAML_TEAM_ATTR: {}
SOCIAL_AUTH_SAML_USER_FLAGS_BY_ATTR: {}
```

On Okta side the admin has set the following mapping
[image: attributes]

Any ideas ?

Thank you